# How can I disable automatic color enhancing of macOS Terminal app?

Tags: macos, terminal

macOS Terminal app has a feature that is not documented, and I will call it **Automatic Color Enhancement** for explnation.

When Terminal app renders ANSI colors, What if the foreground color is too similar with its background color, then It amplifies foreground color to secure more readability.

It's cool feature, but, No thanks.

Can I disable this?

Many oh-my-zsh themes looks broken because of this feature.

[image]